# How to calculate running remaining balace/amounts based on transactions present in multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a follow up of the sale and use of gift cards. 
I want to calculate the running remaining balance of each card.

Specifity : The table i use contains all the trasactions done. ( one transaction per line )  i have an amount of the transaction but no progressive remaining balance.

How can i add a new colonne to calculate the remaining balance after every transaction ( line )

In my table i have many cards numbers with 2 different types of events ( Sale and USE ) and the amount of each transaction, the first transcation always refer to the buying and initial amout of the gift card, the other lines refer to the actual use of the gift card with it's actual amount.

[image]

```
   SELECT C_NUMBER,
   CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'VEN' THEN 'SALE' ELSE 'USE' END AS 
   [EVENT],
    TRANSACTION_DATE, AMOUNT FROM CARDS_TRANSACTION 
    WHERE C_NUMBER in ( '111111111895' , '16222222225082' )
```

I expect the following output : ( New column calculating the difference for the records of event type "Use" because the remaining balance at the event "Sale" is equal to the amount.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
select ct.*,
       sum(case when event = 'SALE' then amount
                when event = 'USE' then - amount
           end) over (partition by number order by trans_date
                     ) as balance
from cards_transaction ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above works fine for unique numbers. 
Unfortunatly, i have lots of empty cards numbers and duplicate numbers also which makes the calculation of the remaining balance false.

I managed to separete the duplicated using the transaction date

```
   SELECT C_NUMBER, CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'VEN' THEN 'SALE' ELSE 'USE' END AS  
   [EVENT], TRANSACTION_DATE, AMOUNT 
   FROM CARDS_TRANSACTION CT
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  CARDS_TRANSACTION  CARDS_TRANSACTION_SALE ON 
   CARDS_TRANSACTION_SALE.EVENT = 'SALE' AND 
   CARDS_TRANSACTION_SALE.C_NUMBER= CT.C_NUMBER AND  
   CARDS_TRANSACTION_SALE.TRANSACTION_DATE = (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) 
   FROM CARDS_TRANSACTION
   WHERE C_NUMBER = CT.C_NUMBER AND 
   EVENT = 'SALE' AND 
   TRANSACTION_DATE <= CT.TRANSACTION_DATE)
```

Is there a way to handle this exception ? the use of a UNION maybe to have more freedome ?

Thanks in advance